# NullPointerException over accessing resource when calling the method from extended class

Tags: java, android

I have an activity class `ClassA` extended from `ListActivity` which has few function that manipulate the UI.

I have another class `ClassB` extended from `ClassA` which handles map related logics. The `ClassB` calls a function `updateNearByNames` of `ClassA`.

But when the function reaches the line where it needs to access a UI resource `findViewById(R.id.namesAround);` it throws a `NullPointerException`.

The UI resource exists and the function works fine if called from within `ClassA`.

```
08-09 22:43:22.705: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-09 22:43:22.705: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-09 22:43:22.705: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
```

Code:

```
public class ClassA extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_v);
        ...

    }
    public void updateNearByNames() {
        Spinner reportEventNamesAroundSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.namesAround); // Error Here
        ...
        ...
    }
}


public class ClassB extends ClassA implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...    
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
            updateNearByNames();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the content view of the Activity? `setContentView()` method

Comment: And is it done before the `findViewById`? Put debug traces on these two methods.

Comment: yes, thats for sure called before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it won't work this way. You can't access the `Views` of an `Activity` by just subclassing it, you will always get an `NPE`. What you need to do is adding a constructor to your second class and pass an instance of your `Activity`.

```
  public ClassB(ClassA a){
   this.a = a;
   //a is a class field
  }
```

later in some method of ClassB:

```
  a.yourMethodInClassAThatAccessesViews();
```

Instantiating `ClassB` from `ClassA`:

```
 ClassB b = new ClassB(this);
```

Another option is adding a public initializer to `ClassB`:

```
   public void initContext(ClassA a){
      this.a = a;
   }
```